# Latent Dirichlet Allocation on Contrived Data

Tags: combinatorics-on-words, mathematical-modeling, machine-learning, computational-linguistics

I am doing a project that seems like it might be susceptible to Latent Dirichlet Allocation. However, my data is highly contrived (both in test cases and use cases) and my "words" don't come close to following [Zipf's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law). When I try testing LDA, it doens't seem to work very well. I've read a few papers on LDA, but I'm having trouble understanding (theoretically) the impact of the word distribution and how to modify the procedure to account for an unusual word distribution.

If anyone has experience with this or references, I would appreciate an explanation at a theoretical level or on a code level.

Comment: You might consider asking on stats.stackexchange .  You may have a more interested audience there.

Comment: @aginensky Thanks! I didn't realize that that existed.